# Already output issue using Map in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to debug Map and I want to see all data in the Map. When I print the Map using `System.debug()` only first item is shown in the logs and after the first item there is message that is saying `already output`.

Are there any workaround for seeing data in Map using `System.debug()` functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by iterating all values in map

```apex
Map<String, String> mapToPrint = new Map<String, String>();

mapToPrint.put('key1', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key2', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key3', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key4', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key5', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key6', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key7', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key8', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key9', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key10', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
mapToPrint.put('key11', 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry');
Boolean contains = mapToPrint.containsKey('Blue');
System.assertEquals(true, contains);

for (String key: mapToPrint.keySet()) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'key: ' + key + ' --> value: ' + mapToPrint.get(key));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Already output is shown when the value that needs to be displayed is the same as previous.

Answer (score 0):

When the same key is used for all subsequent iteration values, the output already displayed.